# How to execute python script in NiFi and put the result output into a file?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a script in python that is connected with sap hana to get the info from a query and then I want to load this info into a .csv file with Apache NiFi.

My python script:

```
codecs.register(lambda s: (
    pyhdb.cesu8.CESU8_CODEC_INFO
    if s in {'cesu-8', 'cesu_8'}
    else None
))

connection = pyhdb.connect(
    host="192.168.xx.xx",
    port=30215,
    user="ùser",
    password="pass"
)

cursor = connection.cursor()
#cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM \"SAPABAP1\".\"BKPF\";")
cursor.execute("select distinct cepc.PRCTR as suc_sucursal_id,cepct.KTEXT as suc_sucursal_desc,csks.BUKRS as soc_sociedad_id FROM \"SAPABAP1\".\"CEPC\" cepc left join \"SAPABAP1\".\"CEPCT\" cepct on  cepc.PRCTR=cepct.PRCTR left join \"SAPABAP1\".\"CSKS\" csks on  csks.KOSTL=cepc.PRCTR where csks.BUKRS in ('1000','1002','2000','3000','3001','4000','5000','5001','7000','8000') and cepct.KTEXT not like '%TEST%';")

x = cursor.fetchall()
#print(type(x))
print("Sucursales:")
print(" ")
print(x)
print(" ")
print(type(x))
print(" ")

f = open("sucursales3.csv", "a", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(x)
f.close()
```

But I don't know how set the output in this script and set it in Nifi to put it into a file.
I have this flow but doesn't work:

[image]

'Execute Stream Command' configuration:
[image]

I don't know why the execute stream command is not executing the python script.

Could some body help me with this flow?

I am very new in Nifi!

Comment: The easiest way to use executestreamcommand and run python executable with your script as parameter then stdout will appear in flowfile content.

Comment: @daggett I edited the post. I have a warning because I haven't got upstream connection. What processor I need to use as upstream?

Comment: put GenerateFlowFile just before ExecuteStreamCommand.

Comment: @daggett thank you for answer me! I added the GenerateFlowFile processor but the script doesn't execute properly. What is the problem?

Comment: i can't guess. you have to publish error message or describe an issue...